# calculate formula with sum of differences of one row with all others in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe

```
value    | count
-----------------
1.8      |  3
1.7      |  2
6.3      |  7
8.4      |  3
```

I would like to create a new column, where each row `i` has the value

```
sum(count[i]*count[j]*(value[i]-value[j])**2,{sum over j where j>i})
```

where `j` spans over all rows with index greater than the one of row `i`.

If I extract the list of values `values = [1.8, 1.7, 6.3, 8.4]` I could evaluate `(value[i]-value[j])**2 for j>i` as

```
def f(m):
    return sum([(values[m] - x)**2 for x in values[m:]])

[f(m) for m in range(len(values))][:-1]
```

but I don't find a way to implement the whole formula in pandas, because also values from a second column are involved. Does anyone can help me?

The expected column, given the dataframe above, would have values [92.61, 817.35, 565.58, 0]

Comment: what is your expected output? Can you post a dataframe of that?

Comment: I've added the expected result and clarified a bit my question

Comment: count[i] and count[j] is unclear. Is count[i] for value 1.7 equal to 2 and count[j] = 2; count[i] for value 6.3 equal to 3 and count[j] = 1; count[i] for value 8.4 equal to 4 and count[j] = 0, etc.?

Comment: count[i] is the value in column count, corresponding to value[i] where i is the number of row. So, count[j] is the corresponding of value[j]. E.g. value[0] = 1.8, count[0] = 3, value[1] = 1.7, count[1]=3. Hope is more clear now

Comment: For row i=0, one has to sum up over j in [1,2,3]. For i=1 one sums from j in [2,3], as i < j in the sum

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `numpy` broadcast

```
v=df.value.values
c=df['count'].values
np.sum(np.tril(c*c[:,None]*((v-v[:,None])**2),-1).T,1)
array([817.35, 565.58,  92.61,   0.  ])
```